# Doctest and qapplication

Tags: qt, doctest

I must integrate doctest lib to a QT core project (Qt5 exactly).

At a point, I need a qcoreapplication to run event loop.
But when I try implement my doctest main with a qcoreapplication it looks doctest context and qcoreapplication parasite themself.
Do there are some workarounds? like qeventloop without qcoreapplication? other ways?
Did someone have already encountered this kind of case with other test libs?
Thanks for answers ;)

Edit 1:
For confidentiality reason i can't share actual base code. But i have same issue with basic code.
At my actual point i fall in an infinite loop at the end of execution.
I may just miss something on QCoreApplication execution end.

```
#define DOCTEST_CONFIG_IMPLEMENT
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include <QSignalSpy>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QEventLoop>
#include "../../Core/external/doctest/doctest.h"


TEST_CASE("Basic class") {
    SUBCASE("2*2") {
        qDebug()<<"2*2";
        CHECK_EQ(2*2, 4);
 }

    SUBCASE("1+1") {
        qDebug()<<"1+1";
        CHECK_EQ(1+1, 2);
    }

    SUBCASE("Termination") {
        qDebug()<<"End!!";
        QCoreApplication::instance()->quit();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    doctest::Context context;

    // defaults
    context.setOption("abort-after", 5);
    context.setOption("order-by", "name");

    QCoreApplication app (argc, argv);
    context.applyCommandLine(argc, argv);
    

    context.setOption("no-breaks", true); 

    int res = context.run();

    if(context.shouldExit()) 
        return res;    
    
    int client_stuff_return_code = 0;
    
    return res + client_stuff_return_code + app.exec(); // the result from doctest is propagated here as well
}
```

Comment: Do you have the actual code to share?

Comment: I added update and base code